# How to optimise the stochastic gradient descent optimiser?

Tags: conv-neural-network, optimization, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am currently looking for a way in which I can optimise the parameters for stochastic gradient descent. These parameters include: the learning rate, momentum, decay and whether to use Nesterov momentum.

The easy solution would be to use `for` loops and try a series of parameter values over a range.

But is there an intuitive way to know how to tune each parameter? 
For instance, which parameter values are a good starting point, and when should I adjust each parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly pick the package default values, and see what the performance was like. Selecting sum of these parameters is known to be a bit fiddly, so there is a whole field of research devoted to finding betters ways to avoid having to do this hyper-parameter tuning of stochastic gradient descent. I would suggest using an algorithm that takes care of some of this work such as Adam or Adadelta. I found [this blog](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html) post very helpful for providing a comparison of the different methods.

If you want to optimise the hyperparameters, this can be quite expense in terms of compute time. Instead of grid search, it is more efficient to use random search for the reasons outlined here (1). If you want to do this in a more complicated (but more efficient) way you can try Bayesian optimisation in package like [Spearmint](https://github.com/JasperSnoek/spearmint) or [BayesOpt](https://rmcantin.bitbucket.io/html/).

(1) Bergstra, James, and Yoshua Bengio. "Random search for hyper-parameter optimization." Journal of Machine Learning Research 13.Feb (2012): 281-305.